# define a function like numpy transpose and inverse

Tags: python, numpy

i would define a function like calculating of inverse `np.matrix.I`:

```
class matrix:
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.I = 1.0/data

  def inv(self):
    return 1.0/self.data

if __name__ == '__main__':
  m = matrix(10)
  m.I
```

it is possible to get calculated value of `m.I` without using `m.inv()` ?

```
In [3]: m.data = 20
In [4]: m.inv()
Out[4]: 0.05
In [5]: m.I
Out[5]: 0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a `property`:

```
class matrix:
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data

  @property
  def I(self):
    return 1.0/self.data

if __name__ == '__main__':
  m = matrix(10)
  print m.I   # 0.1
  m.data = 20
  print m.I   # 0.05
```

(As an aside, I called this class `matrix` as you did, but I'd prefer a different name since the inverse of a matrix is not `1./data`.)